# How to forward two foreign keys from two tables into third table? ASP.NET Core and C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am newbie in .NET Core and I am facing this problem: I have three tables(models): Cases, Contracts and Clients.

Cases.cs

```
public class Cases
{
    [Key]
    public int CaseID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName ="nvarchar(50)")]
    public string OrdinalNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string CaseName { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ClientID")]
    public virtual Clients ClientsID{ get; set; }
    public int ContractID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ContractID")]
    public virtual Contracts ContractsID{ get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName ="nvarchar(11)")]
    public string DateTimeOfOpening { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(11)")]
    public string RequiredDateTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
    public string DescriptionOfFault { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(11)")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Contracts.cs

```
public class Contracts
{
    [Key]
    public int ContractID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(50)")]
    public string ContractNumber { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string ContractName { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ClientID")]
    public virtual Clients Clients { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(11)")]
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(11)")]
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string ResponseTime { get; set; }
}
```

and Clients.cs

```
public class Clients
{
    [Key]
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public int IDNumber { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string Place { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cases> Cases{ get; set; }
}
```

What I want is to forward **ClientID** and **ContractID** from these two tables to **Cases** table, but it's not possible. Everytime I try to do that there is an error like:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Cases_Contracts_ContractID' on table 'Cases' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
> What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To help yourself in the future, I would write or say the relationship out loud, it'll help you understand how it works.

If I understand correctly, A Client Has A Contract and this relationship is defined as a Case with additional properties.

So a better way of putting it, A client has a Case which has a contract.

To fix this, remove the relationship between clients and contracts, this relationship is achieved through the Case table.

Instead A client has a case, and A contract has a case, and a case has a contract and a client.

in Contracts.cs
Remove ClientId and Client, replace with CaseId and Case

This should fix your problem.